# Why referencing a .Net standard nuget package in a .Net 4.7.2 project import a lot of .Net core lib?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I'm having a .Net 4.7.2 application, in which I want to reference the package `OpcFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua`. This project as a list of dependencies for .Net 4.6 that is quite small.

But when I install it, I get like 50+ additional packages to install. Is there a way to reduce this? I feel that a lot of thoses classes are already existing in the full .Net project(System.Threading.Tasks/Timer/...).

Thank you

Comment: if that's what the package has decided it requires in order to work, I doubt there's much you can do about it - if they are set as dependencies then it's unlikely to run correctly without them. Someone else might know better than me, but at a basic level that's what dependencies are for! Plus, even if you think there's a package with the same name already in .NET Framework, it doesn't mean it functions in exactly the same way, so it may not be directly replaceable.

Comment: lol; one of the dependencies is Kestrel - Kestrel imports *everything*...

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah I see, but adding 82 nuggets others packages is just a pain in the ass :'(. I've to manually check for each of them if it's something new for our solution, if it's something that has several version(like 4.5.2 and 4.6.2, with only one of them having a real lib) if it's required. Lot of tears here

Comment: @MarcGravell Do you have any idea why things like System.Runtime seems to be required?

Comment: @J4N because of having to support .NET Standard and resolve the *actual runtime* - note that in your case, it'll just be type-forwarded, but... check the "commonly used types" here - I strongly suspect that you, or Kestrel, has used one (or possibly all!) of these... https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I would expect to have just then a `TypeForwardedTo` pointing to the .Net framework, but in my case I've a lot of them with some real DLL.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at many of these types (which are supplied by .NET Standard packages, not .NET Core), you'll find that the specific version that's used against .NET 4.7.2 will be an empty assembly just containing lots of [`TypeForwardedTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attributes pointing right back at the full-flavour .NET Framework.

So you still end up using the exact types you always would have done. There's just extra indirections which allows .NET Standard to work with both .NET Framework, .NET Core and other .NET Standard implementations.

Comment: You're right. It's just painful to configure my wix setup with all thoses packages to check.

Comment: I still cannot understand why things like System.Runtime are package that are imported with DLL.

Comment: Same for things like Linq, why should I reference this DLL? We already have this in .Net Framework